# Why would I need a blank layout at the bottom of a view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a rather intense view layout. It makes uses of @drawable/shape.xml files and styles.

All the elements are matched properly

But, it will not compile unless I had a blank layout at the bottom - the compiler just says "Error parsing XML"

I add this and it works:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Without knowing the rest of the layout it's hard to tell :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing two LinearLayouts in your posted code.

1. This LinearLayout terminates itself with `/>`:

   ```
   <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       android:orientation="vertical" 
       />
   ```
2. And this one terminates a previous LinearLayout:

   ```
   <LinearLayout> <!-- Somewhere above in your code -->
       ...
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

You can safely remove the empty `<LinearLayout ... />` layout if you keep the closing `</LinearLayout>` tag. If this is not the answer, you need to post the entire XML so we can see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks @Sam, that was it! An </ImageView> had snuck in there after it had already been terminated. Cheers!